# LoadException on adding a controller to fxml file in Java 8

Tags: java, javafx, model-view-controller, netbeans, scenebuilder

Every time i add a controller to the fxml file, i get an exception: javafx.fxml.LoadException, and when i print the exception message it shows the right directory to the file

I am using netbeans 8 IDE, Java 8 and Scene builder for the GUI

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="419.0" prefWidth="875.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="organizer.Controller.DeleteCategoryController">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutX="9.0" layoutY="108.0" prefHeight="283.0" prefWidth="550.0" style="-fx-border-width: 1pt; -fx-border-color: black;">
         <children>
            <Text fx:id="textDeleteThen" layoutX="195.0" layoutY="27.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Delete ... category then" />
            <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="166.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="103.0" prefWidth="241.0" text="Option 3&#10;Create a new Relationship &#10;and move contacts having ..... &#10;relationship to this relationship" />
            <Button layoutX="266.0" layoutY="49.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="103.0" prefWidth="241.0" text="Option 2&#10;Keep all contacts &#10;with the .... relationship" />
         </children></Pane>
      <Pane layoutX="569.0" layoutY="19.0" prefHeight="372.0" prefWidth="272.0" style="-fx-border-width: 1pt; -fx-border-color: black;" />
      <Text layoutX="41.0" layoutY="73.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Choose one of the following options" wrappingWidth="447.681640625" />
      <Text fx:id="textDeletingCategory" layoutX="42.0" layoutY="24.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Deleting ..." />
      <Text fx:id="textMessage" layoutX="42.0" layoutY="48.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="After deleting .... do the following:" />
      <Button alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="279.0" layoutY="271.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="103.0" prefWidth="241.0" text="Option 4&#10;Change Contacts having &#10;.... relationship &#10;to the following &#10;existing relationship" />
      <Button layoutX="23.0" layoutY="153.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="103.0" prefWidth="241.0" text="Option 1&#10;Delete all contacts &#10;with the ..... relationship" />
      <TextField layoutX="585.0" layoutY="56.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="184.0" />
      <ListView fx:id="listViewRemainingCategories" layoutX="580.0" layoutY="138.0" prefHeight="236.0" prefWidth="241.0" />
      <Text layoutX="580.0" layoutY="115.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="List of other categories (for option 4)" />
      <Text layoutX="585.0" layoutY="39.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="New Category Name (for option 3)" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And Controller:

```
package organizer.Controller;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import organizer.Model.SQL_Objects;


public class DeleteCategoryController extends SQL_Objects implements Initializable{

    @FXML private ListView listViewRemainingCategories;
    @FXML private Text textDeletingCategory;
    @FXML private Text textMessage;
    @FXML private Text textDeleteThen;

    private int toRemoveId;
    private String toRemoveName;
    private int associatedRecordsCount;

    public DeleteCategoryController(String toRemoveName, int toRemoveId, int associatedRecordCount) {
        this.toRemoveName = toRemoveName;
        this.toRemoveId = toRemoveId;
        this.associatedRecordsCount = associatedRecordCount;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }
```

all other FXML files in my program work well, it is just this FXML file, and no matter which controller i add to it, it prevents it from loading, when i remove the controller attribute it opens normally.

Full stack trace:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/D:/Personal/Projects/Tools/Java/Organizer/dist/run798015614/Organizer.jar!/organizer/View/DeleteCategory.fxml:10

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:932)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at organizer.Controller.Main.switchWindow(Main.java:32)
    at organizer.Controller.Main.start(Main.java:21)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: organizer.Controller.DeleteCategoryController
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: organizer.Controller.DeleteCategoryController.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    ... 25 more
```

Any idea why ?
I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution, i will post here so someone might make use of that
When i removed the constructor the program worked, looks like in the JavaFx applications you can only have the default constructor, however if you need to add parameters to the constructor you then need to use what is known as ControllerFactory.